# Isotope J-query will not automatically arrange unless window is resized or link clicked twice?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-isotope

http://iledan.me/portfolio.html

On the link above the Isotope J-query organizes stuff fine only if I resize the window, reclick the "portfolio" link, or click on of the two links that organizes the images ("digital" and "print"). If the page has been loaded before, it organizes itself fine (cache/cookies).

(I realize there is some inconsistency in the layout between browsers, this site is a work in progress).

Answer (score 0):

I feel stupid now. It didn't want to organize them unless I clicked a category (all, digital, or print) because I specified a width for each image but not a height.